# FINDSTR - force separation of results into different lines?

Tags: cmd, findstr

When I run `findstr` on a directory full of files, for some reason it will output all the results to a single line.

What I mean by this is, if I have say a number of text files:

```
fileone.txt
filetwo.txt
filethree.txt
filefour.txt
```

Now I say

```
findstr "mystring" *.txt
```

The output will look like:

> **fileone.txt:** blah blah blah mystring **filetwo.txt:** yada mystring yada yada **filethree.txt:** Gobbledymystringgook

I suspect that is because each file contains a single line with no newline or carriage return at the end.

Is it possible to force findstr to separate the results out into separate lines?

(I want to pipe it as an input to another search, e.g. `findstr "mystring" *.txt | findstr /V  "yada"`, but the subsequent search treats the entire output as one big line)

Comment: Would you consider using powershell's `Select-String` instead?

Comment: @Yarin_007 - Yes powershell's `Select-String` did the job perfectly for me, thanks! Maybe that should be posted as an answer?

Comment: `for %I in (*.txt) do findstr "mystring" < "%~I"`?